# where should i place maniphest.custom-field-definitions in phabricator

Tags: phabricator

where should i place maniphest.custom-field-definitions in phabricator to create new custom field in maniphest

```
{
  "mycompany:estimated-hours": {
    "name": "Estimated Hours",
    "type": "int",
    "caption": "Estimated number of hours this will take.",
    "required": true
  },
  "mycompany:actual-hours": {
    "name": "Actual Hours",
    "type": "int",
    "caption": "Actual number of hours this took."
  },
  "mycompany:company-jobs": {
    "name": "Job Role",
    "type": "select",
    "options": {
      "mycompany:engineer": "Engineer",
      "mycompany:nonengineer": "Other"
    }
  },
  "mycompany:favorite-dinosaur": {
    "name": "Favorite Dinosaur",
    "type": "text"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to config on the main menu and then scroll down until under Applications Configuration there's a link to maniphest.
There, click on the field name you want to change and paste the new value